# use one large external file for many javascript templates with backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, ejs

I have two different HTML pages that serve up backbone apps. Up until now, I have put all the js templates inside of each respective HTML file.

Now, I'm refactoring a bit and would like to share some backbone views between files. When loading a view that can't find a js template, the whole app will error out. I know the proper way to merge these two would be to have external js templates, using EJS for example, and have 1 template per file, however, I'd like to just have one huge HTML file with embedded `<script type='text/template'>` and share the template HTML file between my 2 pages. Is this possible? I tried getting the external js templates with AJAX and writing them to the head, but backbone views still can't find them.

Does anyone else choose to have a file with many javascript templates in it? I also find that I have an unmanageable number of files open when I use ejs. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use an extra javascript/coffeescript file and use [underscore's templating](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) to take care of everything. This way you can include the templates and put them into as few (or many) files as you would like.

Comment: So, how do you identify which template you want to use? I am currently seperating them all in HTML like so. <script type="text/template" id="widget_config"> It would seem illogical to me to have a <script> tag inside of a javascript file.

Comment: aww wait I see... var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
So you would create a global variable called compiled in this case and render it in your backbone views?

Comment: I use a global namespace for them, say for example:
  MyApp.headerTemplate = _.template('<header><%= name %></header>');
  MyApp.sidebarTemplate = _.template('<div class="sidebar"><ul></ul></div>');
}
Then call them:
render: function() {
  var header = MyApp.headerTemplate({name: 'MySite'});
  $(this.el).append(header);
  return this;
}

Comment: The thing I don't like about this method is that my IDE (Netbeans) will not help me write HTML inside a JS file.  Any solutions around this?  Better IDE?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a single file for all the templates on my current project and it is working out pretty well.

It's a Asp.Net site, so I made the template file into a user control so I can easily include it in any page that uses Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fetching all templates through AJAX, maybe you don't have to write them to the head.

You can send templates to the client as JSON Object, for example:

```
{"about":"<p>About</p>...","gallery":"<p>Gallery</p>...","contact":"<p>Contact</p>..."}
```

After fetching temples you can store them as templates variable inside some object(or locale storage), and after that you can do the following:

```
var tempStr = templates['about'],
    template = new EJS({element:{value: tempStr, id: 'about'}}),
    content = template.render();
```